# Why is my rigging constantly stretching ad deforming my model?

Tags: rigging, armature

[image]I've been using Blender for a little while now and one thing I can never seem to get right is how to stop the armature from deforming and stretching my model. I've been practicing on a low poly model I made but even in this one I can't get the armature right. I've tried weight painting and it doesn't seem to have much of an effect, not to mention whenever I try to get the clothes to move with the model it messes up even more. Can someone explain to me what I've been doing wrong? I will attach the file I have been working with. Than you!

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=oa2kxx6G" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/oa2kxx6G/)

Comment: Suggestion.  Please show the failure and successes of your model with wisely chosen screen screen captures.  I see you have you included a blend file.   Some people would prefer to see screen captures first.

Comment: For clothing .. some people use another modifier in addition to armature modifiers .. I think it is the cage modifier ... so for clothing 2 modifiers are better than one

Comment: I think your question is too broad or not precise enough. About the cloth: it doesn't follow the bent of the arm because it can't, you haven't created any edge loop on the middle of the sleeve., it needs at least one and ideally 3 close to each other so that it bends smoothly.